# AngularJS 'agnostic' and 'component' directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, client-side

Recently I have a violence dispute with my colleague about the most flexible way of directive usage in the AngularJS. After long and exhausted discussion we agreed to ask a community to judge our quarrel. Please help us with it :)

**If speak briefly I am strongly believe that to make something really flexible the main MVC principle should be followed to - strictly separation logic from presentation and it doesn't matter what kind of 'scope' we have.** It is just preferable way to use any MVC framework. My colleague doesn't agree with me and strongly believe that directive in AngularJS is something very 'special' for AngularJS and valid only if it has all in the 'board' like template + 'own' controller. Also he claims that it is pretty fine to have a direct manipulation with DOM in scope of the directive and all 'directives' should work in such manner...

We have an idea to implement the ability 'just in place' entity editing. It should work in the following manner - user just click to some 'text' and it should be possible to change the value of it.

I suggest the following approach to it:

**template (text-editor.html):**

```
<label class="title">{{title}}</label>
<span class="value" ng-show="!editor.edited[name]" ng-click="editor.activateEditing(name)">{{editor.entity[name]}}</span>
<input ng-show="editor.edited[name]" ng-model="editor.entity[name]" ng-change="editor.validate(name)"></input>
```

**controller:**

```
function editorController ($scope, $controller) {
    function copy (source) {
      var result = {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.charAt(0) !== '_') {
          result[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    $scope.edited = {};

    $scope.activateEditing = function (name) {
      var entity = $scope.entity;

      $scope.edited[name] = true;

      if (!entity._backup) {
        entity._backup = copy(entity);
      }
    };

    $scope.cancelEditing = function () {
      var entity = $scope.entity, backup = entity._backup;
      for (var prop in backup) {
        if (backup.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          entity[prop] = backup[prop];
        }
      }

      delete entity._backup;
      $scope.edited = {};
    };

    $scope.saveEditing = function () {
      var entity = $scope.entity, backup = entity._backup;
      $scope.$emit('saveEntity', entity, backup);

      delete entity._backup; 
      $scope.edited = {};
    };

    $scope.deleteEntity = function () {
      var entity = $scope.entity;
      $scope.$emit('deleteEntity', entity);

      delete entity._backup; 
      $scope.edited = {};
    };

    $scope.$on('trackEntity', function (event, entity) {
      $scope.entity = entity;
      $scope.edited = {};
    });
  }

  editorController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller'];
  app.controller('EditorCtrl', editorController);
```

**directive:**

```
function textEditor() {
    return {
      scope: {
        title: '=',
        name: '=',
        editor: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/text-editor.html',
    };
  }

  app.directive('textEditor', textEditor);
```

**usage:**

```
<div ng-controller="EditorCtrl">
  <div class="stack-item" ng-if="show">
    <div class="stack-item-header" ng-include="'partials/section-header.html'"></div>

    <div class="details-menu">
      <div class="details-actions">
        <div class="details-edit-actions">
          <a ng-click="saveEditing()"><span class="icon-save"></span>Save</a>
          <a ng-click="cancelEditing()"><span class="icon-cancel"></span>Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Medication</legend>
        <div text-editor title="'Drug Name'" name="'drugName'" editor="this"></div>
        <div text-editor title="'Dosage'" name="'dosage'" editor="this"></div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

validate function is out of scope of our discussion it is defined in the scope in a some way...

So as you can see my directive is completely agnostic - it only used just for template provide some additional parameters for template.

My colleague suggests other solution:

**sample of usage:**

```
<div content-link>
  <a link ng-bind="case.info.caseName"></a>
  <input content ng-model="case.info.caseName" />
</div>
```

**directive:**

```
﻿(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('xx')
        .directive('contentLink', contentLink)

    contentLink.$inject = ['$compile'];
    function contentLink($compile) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                contentActive: '=?'
            },
            link: link,
            controller: ContentLinkController,
            controllerAs: 'contentLink',
            template: '<div class="cl-link" ng-hide="contentLink.contentActive" ng-click="contentLink.toggleContent()"></div>' +
                      '<div class="cl-content" ng-show="contentLink.contentActive" outside-click="contentLink.toggleContent()" outside-if="contentLink.contentActive" ' +
                            'ignore-element-selectors="{{ contentLink.otherContentElements }}">' +
                      '</div>'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            angular.extend(scope.contentLink, {
                toggleContent: toggleContent
            });

            element.removeAttr('content-link').addClass('content-link');

            transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone, innerScope) {
                clone.filter('[link]').removeAttr('link').appendTo(element.find('.cl-link'));
                clone.filter('[content]').removeAttr('content').appendTo(element.find('.cl-content'));
            });

            var deregisterScopeDestroyListener = scope.$on('$destroy', cleanup);

            function toggleContent() {
                scope.contentActive = scope.contentLink.contentActive = !scope.contentLink.contentActive;

                element.toggleClass('content-active', scope.contentLink.contentActive);
            }

            function cleanup() {
                scope.contentLink = null;
                deregisterScopeDestroyListener();
            }
        }
    }

    ContentLinkController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs'];
    function ContentLinkController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
            contentActive: $scope.contentActive || false,
            otherContentElements: $attrs.otherContentElements
        });
    }
})();
```

So it seems that it doesn't solve problem of cancellation of editing but my colleague just pointed out that it is not necessary - it can be done by some way on the 'different' layer.

**So we would like to create some 'reusable' things in the scope of a big application - which solution seems more reasonable from your point of view?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the first approach.

My problem with the second approach is that it goes against the grain of angular methodology. The second approach is closer to the "component" style, which is a valid and recommended style in other frameworks like ExtJs where the entire component is bundled. I don't believe that style should be imported into Angular.

At a much more simpler world view - I could understand the first approach in a single glance, whereas I simply gave up on the second approach. Pragamatic development also means that we work in teams and maintainability and ease of change trump other deep philosophical concerns.

Also - Please don't have violent discussions :)

Comment: Thank you! I also strongly believe that simplicity is a key point of success. And as all deep things - the truth is a paradoxical the most simple things very difficult to achieve :)